# How to control MediaPlayer starting delay?

Tags: android, delay, android-mediaplayer

Firstly, my aim is to play a sound on my devices with the same start    time. Even a **delay of 100ms** is very important for me. So i must    be very careful on that delay management.

Assume that i synchronize my all devices with using network time protocol. I am connecting **0.tr.pool.ntp.org** and with added delays i have a data like that:

- Your system time: 14:45:50.255000 **(a)** On my device
- NTP time: 14:46:01.255000 **(b)**

It is working fine. I have a BroadcastReceiver class as an Alarm Receiver. Again for example, i will play a sound at 14:50:00.000 and that given to AlarmManager like **((14:50:00.000) - (a - b))** for synchronization with NTP server.

Up to here everything is great. My problem is beginning with a delay of almost 250ms **(c)** on BroadcastReceiver. This delay is never goes 1000ms++ . I solved this issue with changing Alarm time to **((14:50:00.000) - (a - b) - 1000ms)** then on BroadcastReceiver i add a delay of **(1000ms - c)** . It is still great thank god :)

Final step is playing sound, it is very easy just add this code block:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.mysound); 
player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.release();
    }
});
player.start();
```

This code works but what about delay? I decide to measure this delay on the beginning of my app and save it to use when the time comes. I use that method:

```
private void synchronizeMediaPlayer(){
    long startMs = new Date().getTime();
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.mysound); 
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
            player.release();
        }
    });
    player.start();
    long finishMs = new Date().getTime();
    delayPlayer = finishMs - startMs; // this is static variable for using in any class
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}
```

Ok. Again this `delayPlayer` is never goes 1000ms++ . Then as you can estimate, i changed Alarm time to **((14:50:00.000) - (a - b) - 1000ms - 1000ms)** then added a delay of **(1000ms - delayPlayer)** before playing sound. I think this is the most reasonable way.

**Result:** Now after all these steps, my sound is starting with a little delay(like 50ms-250ms) between the devices. I measured all the delays and controlled every step. Everything is right but the only problem is `delayPlayer`. I thought, it is changing always with respect to devices state(RAM usage, Background Services, etc.). Frankly, i started to think this changes are not depending on device state. Because i measured it with an interval of 1 minute, then saw that it is always changing. This changings are very different like; now 150ms, after 1 min it goes 300ms.

How can i solve that MediaPlayer delay issue? I think you awesome programmers can help me.

**Note:** My English may not be good. Sorry for that...

Comment: use TimingLogger to profile your synchronizeMediaPlayer() method.  what do you see?

Comment: I can see mediaplayer start and stop times from my LogCat already. It is same as my variable `delayPlayer`.

Comment: see how long MediaPlayer.create() takes, thats why i suggested to use TimingLogger

Comment: Ok i understand but the problem is not measuring. the problem is measurements are not the same, never be the same of previous measurement.

Comment: and thats why i suggested to profile it, i suspect MediaPlayer.create() takes long (and unknown) time so you can call  MediaPlayer.create() in advance and only call start(0 when needed

Comment: @BatuhanCoşkun I face same requirement and i stuck in this kind of delay ... Can you please help me for same?